# How can I turn a string into a list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

so what I'm working on is a coursework task for school (in python 3.5.1). One of my tasks is to have the user input a unique code and it will search through the document and print the whole line that the code is in. If they put in "E5341" it will print out "E5341,21/09/2015,C102,440,E,0". What I currently have works great.

```
def optionA():
    estimateNumber = input ("Please enter an estimate number")
    handle = open ("paintingJobs.txt")
    for line in handle:
        if line.startswith(estimateNumber) :
            print (line)
```

However, I need to print out the line in a list in this format (minus the bullet points. They're just there to  separate each line)

- Estimate Number:
- Estimate Date:
- Customer ID:
- Status
- Estimate Amount:

And I have no clue how to do so. Any help is gratefully appreciated. By the way, after each comma in "E5341,21/09/2015,C102,440,E,0" is the new list heading. E5341 being Estimate Number, 21/09/2015 is Estimate Date etc.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working in a school coursework I will not give you the code but just directions.

If all the attributes in line returned are comma separated you should use 'split' function in Python. Refer documentation to learn how to use it. If you want to print it line by line append newline character to each member of the output of split function (Instead of looping try using 'map' function for this task, you may end up learning a thing or two :-) ).

Comment: Hi, so I've now saved the line which is found in the txt file. So would I split it and then output it through the map function? Also, how would I add the "Estimate Details" etc. on? Thanks again!